# Network drive data security - how to restrict access

Tags: networking, samba

I have an Ubuntu machine. I share my data with three windows machine through samba on a wifi network and I want to restrict other Windows machines having access to that data.

For example, if anyone who is connected to my wifi network with a Windows machine and goes to network options and then map the network drive and enters the Ubuntu machine's network path there he/she can access that Ubuntu drive. I want to restrict those machine access to my drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict access by IP by editing your /etc/samba/smb.conf like this:

```
[global]
...
# Override the default network interface list that Samba will use for browsing.
interfaces = eth0, 127.0.0.1

# Limit what interfaces on a machine will serve SMB requests.
bind interfaces only = yes

# List, IP range etc. of hosts that are not allowed to access Samba services.
# In case of conflict between 'hosts allow' and 'hosts deny', the 'allow' list will take precedence.
hosts deny = ALL

# List, IP range etc. of hosts that are allowed to access Samba services
hosts allow = 192.168.0.127.
...
```

Remember to edit the above with your own network information.

- Change eth0 to be your network interface.  For example, mine is `enp3s0`
- Change the `hosts allow =` line to match the IP addresses of the machines you want to have access to the shares

Comment: You're welcome.  I hope it works out for you :)